# Restful Web service issue - HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, restful-architecture

I am trying one restful web service example so when I am going to hit url that time I am getting HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available

below are the detail of my code, if you want any other information let me know

Web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <display-name>User Management</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.tutorialspoint</param-value>
         </init-param>
      </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

Service class

```html
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService {

   UserDao userDao = new UserDao();

   @GET
   @Path("/users")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public List<User> getUsers(){
      return userDao.getAllUsers();
   }    
}
```

ALL jars

[image]

Tomcat webapps

[image]

Comment: What is the request? Any output from the log?

Comment: Add logs and specify till what point your request has reached?

Comment: thanks sheetal for your response.......  Request - http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users      and in logs I am not getting anything

Comment: @vijendra can you try after modifying the param value to com.tutorialspoint.UserManagement in web.xml

Comment: thanks  for your suggestion :)  .. this issue has  been  resolved

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, your URL shoud be `http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users`.

Also you can try to delete * in `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>`

Comment: I am using the same URL

Comment: after hitting url "http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users" I am not getting any update in log file

Comment: thanks  for your suggestion .. this issue has  been  resolved

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved,

Actually my web.xml was not on correct place that is why I was getting the "The requested resource is not available" . The file web.xml should be placed inside WEB-INF folder

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. I correct it with modifying the web.xml, when decalring the servlet.

```html
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.webservice.messenger.ressources</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

My package was declared :

```html
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.webservice.messenger.messengers</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

while my classes were on package : org.webservice.messenger.ressources

I hope it s clear now.

Comment: could you please elaborate?